# PHP IDE Commenting (Netbeans)

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, comments

How to make good commenting for PHP IDE (actually i using NetBeans)

my target is when i using a class or function there is will be a explanation about it's function, like when i typing

```
mysql_connect("param", "param");
```

there is will be a popup explanation about it function what it parameter and the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHPDoc style comments

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.pkg.html